# OpenGL ES shader multi textures

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d, shader

I'm working on creating a 3D landscape. So far I've got a mesh created with vertices and faces, and it all looks decent. I've applied a single texture to it, but want to have multiple textures perhaps based on the height. I'm thinking I need a shader to do this.

I'm new to shaders but so far I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/multi-texture/) and have two textures blended together. However, I want to fade one texture out completely at certain heights (or position) and have the other completley show.

I'm really not sure how to approach this using a shader. Could someone give some advice on how to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For argument's sake, suppose your source geometry runs from y=0 to y=1 and you want the second texture to be completely transparent at y=0 and completely opaque at y=1. Then you could add an addition varying, named `secondTextureAlpha` or something like that. Load it with your pre-transformation y values in the shader, then combine the incoming values from the source textures either so that the second is multiplies by `secondTextureAlpha`, if you want to stick with additive blending, or via the `mix` function for multiplicative.

So e.g. the fragement shader might end up looking like:

```
varying vec3 lightDir,normal;
varying lowp float secondTextureAlpha;
uniform sampler2D tex,l3d;

void main()
{
    vec3 ct,cf;
    vec4 texel;
    float intensity,at,af;
    intensity = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);

    cf = intensity * (gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse).rgb +
                      gl_FrontMaterial.ambient.rgb;
    af = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a;
    texel = mix(texture2D(tex,gl_TexCoord[0].st),

          texture2D(l3d,gl_TexCoord[0].st), secondTextureAlpha);
    ct = texel.rgb;
    at = texel.a;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ct * cf, at * af);

}
```

To achieve a more complicated mapping, just adjust how you load `secondTextureAlpha` in your vertex shader, or take it as an input attribute maybe.

Comment: does this need anything in particular in the vertex shader (sorry I am new to shaders and can't tell without trying it- which I can't do until I get home)

Comment: Yes, you'd need to specify values for `secondTextureAlpha` at the vertices. I suggested just loading them with your source y. The tutorial you link to is for desktop OpenGL so its vertex shader doesn't directly adapt — I therefore assumed you had different code from it and didn't try to guess how that already looks.

Comment: Yeah, I had to adapt it for Opengl ES, but also I'm using an API which loads in some variables for you automatically (which is why I didn't post any source code, so it wouldn't confuse matters)

Comment: One way or the other you're probably going to want to load the extra varying from the vertex shader. If you're getting world position through then you could use that directly in the fragment shader subject to the consideration that any fixed calculations on world position will be performed once per fragment rather than once per vertex.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark this correct. I took a while for me to get around to actually test it. But it seems to work, thanks!